# Design pattern to render tree structured data

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the following problem statement:
(1)User of a site can subscribe to more than one subscription.
(2)Each subscription can contain many articles and the articles are tagged based on one of the three categories: Science, Economics & Culture.
This is how i can describe the data structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtaHx.jpg

My Job is to render this stuff as shown below and the user can have 'n' subscriptions.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/faQlp.jpg

I have already accomplished this by using a lot of hashmaps and arraylist, the code looks shoddy and this will not scale up as the number of subscriptions for a user increases - Perf is taking a huge hit.
Please suggest a good design to implement this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For a scenario like this, the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) and the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) come to mind.  The latter, specifically, will allow to separate the structure of your tree from the traversal of the tree.